# MacBook Pro Retina not charging

Tags: macbook-pro

So my MacBook was on 2% so I tried charging it but it worked at first ,but then a little later another message came up saying that the macbook was low battery and then I realized that the cord was not plugged in so I plugged it in to my MacBook but it won't charge this time. I figured since the computer was kinda overheated I decieded to shut it down and then charge it but now it won't charge, I even used a different charger (that works) but nothing and using a different outlet as well. When I try turning it on it just has simple of needing to be charge but when I plug in a charger it won't charge my MacBook at all. Can someone tell me what to do?????

Answer (score 1):

It is possible your Power Management got messed up

Reset the SMC following [this instructions](http://support.apple.com/da-dk/HT3964):.

That should fix the problem, unless your battery is fried.